# Get all AsyncTasks that are executed and currently running in Android app

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a number of `AsyncTask` instances that are downloading some different content from the server. They run on executor:

```
final GetStationsTask getStationsTask = new GetStationsTask();
getStationsTask
        .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, URL_STATIONS);
```

Currently I have 3 subclasses of `AsyncTask`, but this number will not stay the same. I am also implementing some kind of retrying for tasks that were not completed for different reasons, and I would like to download everything from the beginning, if at least one of the tasks was not finished correctly (the data was not received):

```
// mHandler = new Handler(); // an instance variable
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!allDataSet()) {
            // here I want to cancel the tasks that are still running
            // and rerun all of them
        }
    }
}, 30000); // I give all the tasks 30 seconds to complete
```

For that I suppose I need to know which tasks are currently running, which tasks have finished correctly and which ones were cancelled, because if all the tasks get restarted, I need to cancel the running ones first to prevent the data from being received multiple times. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: You may need to re-think your strategy. What are you actually doing? Downloading in chunks?

Comment: @Sufian I call multiple APIs and the servers are not mine, so I can't merge the APIs into one response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of tasks is unknown, but they need to communicate in some way.
I would suggest to create 2 classes:

1. YourTask class - all needed tasks would be it's instances
2. TaskMediator - which manage communication as [Mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) Design Pattern

So every time one task **(YourTask)** created it register it's self
    to predefined class **(TaskMediator)** which manage their communication.

That way you get looser coupling between their objects,
  but still keeps one communication channel

*By the way your TaskMediator can be [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) as suggested by *Marcin Jedrzejewski*

Answer (score 2):

Override the base AsyncTask, and use that as your base class for all AsyncTasks. Have the overriden task have a static list of running, cancelled and finished tasks. Then add each task to the relevant list in the base class methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a list of AsyncTasks being currently executed in some singleton class, ie. Application extended one.:

```
List<AsyncTask<String, String, String>> downloadsAsycs = new ArrayList<AsyncTask<String, String, String>>();
```

inside of your asynctask's onPostExecute remove it from list using `downloadsAsycs.remove(this)`. Remember to either synchronize on using this list, or always modify/read it on UI thread, ie. inside Handler from mainlooper or in onPreExecute/onPostExecute. You can check status of your async task using `AsyncTask.getStatus()`. After a while it starts getting complicated.

You could also switch from AsyncTask to [Executors.newFixedThreadPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) and [ExecutorService.invokeAll](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20java.util.concurrent.Callable%3CT%3E%3E,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). You could invoke all your tasks and have returned Future for all of them which allow to control them. You could even use [Future.get](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) with timeout on some back thread (even asynctask.doInBackground) to 30s, and after this time use [Future.cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) if operation timed out.